# How to find a number with no digit occurring more than once (J3 CCC 2013 from 1987 to 2013)

Tags: java

I'm a grade 11 student and have been given the task to complete this question for homework:

> Problem J3/S1: From 1987 to 2013
>
> You might be surprised to know that 2013 is the first year since 1987
> with distinct digits.
> The years 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019
> each have distinct digits.
> 2012 does not have distinct digits,
> since the digit 2 is repeated.
>
> **Given a year, what is the next year with distinct digits?**
>
> Input
> The input consists of one integer *Y* (0 ≤ *Y* ≤ 10000),
> representing the starting year.
>
> Output
> The output will be the single integer *D*,
> which is the next year after *Y* with distinct digits.
>
> Sample Input 1
> *1987*
> Sample Output 1
> `2013`
>
> Sample Input 2
> *999*
> Sample Output 2
> `1023`

I usually answer these types of questions rather quickly but I am stumped when it comes to this one. I have spent several hours and cannot figure it out. I found out How to identify if a number is distinct or not, but I can't figure out how to add on years and check again, I keep getting errors. I would really appreciate someone's help.

Please keep in mind that I am in grade 11 and this is my first year of working with Java, so please do not use advanced coding, and methods because I won't understand. If you can, please answer it in a class and not the main method.

here is what I tried:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Leavemealone
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    BufferedReader objReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int ctr = 0;
    String inputStr = "";
    int input = 0;
    int inputCheck = 0;
    
    System.out.println("Enter somthin: "); 
    input = Integer.parseInt (objReader.readLine ());
    
    while(ctr == 0)
    {
      inputStr += input;

      Scanner sc = new Scanner(inputStr);
      int n = sc.nextInt(); // get year
      String s = String.valueOf(n);

      int[] num = new int[4];
      for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
      {
        int x = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(i, i + 1)); // integer at this part in the string
        num[i] += x;
      }

      String apple = (num[0] + "" + num[1] + "" + num[2] + "" + num[3]);
      if (num[0] != num[1] && 
          num[1] != num[2] && 
          num[2] != num[3] && 
          num[0] != num[2] && 
          num[0] != num[3] &&
          num[1] != num[3])
      {
        ctr++;
        //distinct
      }
      else
      {
        input++;
        //not distinct
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

this is the other code I found online, I just don't know how to put it in a class

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class Thegoodone
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader objReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (System.in));
    int ctr = 0;
    String input = "";
    int inputCheck = 0;
    
    while (ctr == 0)
    {
      System.out.println("Enter somthin: "); 
      inputCheck = Integer.parseInt (objReader.readLine ());
      if (inputCheck > 0 && inputCheck < 10000) 
      {
        input += inputCheck;
        ctr += 1; 
      }
      else
      {
        System.out.println("invalid input ");
      }
    }
    
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(input);
  
    int n = sc.nextInt(); // get year
    n++; // start from the next year
    while (!hasDistinctDidgets(n)) //if there is repeating digits
    {
      n++;// next year
    }
    System.out.println(n);// prints year
}
  
public static boolean hasDistinctDidgets(int n)
{
  //System.out.println("a" + n);
  String s = String.valueOf(n); // converts the year from int to String
  int[] numbers = new int[10]; // index position represents number, element value represents occurrence of that number
  for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
  {
    int x = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(i, i + 1)); // integer at this part in the string
    numbers[x]++; //increase occurrence of this integer in the array
  }
  //check if any digit occurred more than once in the array
  for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i ++)
  {
    if (numbers[i] > 1) //digit occurred more than once
    {
      return false; //not distinct
    }
  }
  return true; // hasn't returned false yet, so the integer has distinct digits
}
}
```

so this is how I tried to put it in a class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class Danny3
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader objReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (System.in));
    int ctr = 0;
    String input = "";
    int inputCheck = 0;
    
    while (ctr == 0)
    {
      System.out.println("Enter somthin: "); 
      inputCheck = Integer.parseInt (objReader.readLine ());
      if (inputCheck > 0 && inputCheck < 10000) 
      {
        input += inputCheck;
        ctr += 1; 
      }
      else
      {
        System.out.println("invalid input ");
      }
    }
    
  
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(input);
  
  
     
     
    // System.out.println(output);
  
    int n = sc.nextInt(); // get year
    n++; // start from the next year
    DistinctCheck processing = new DistinctCheck(n);
    int output = processing.getSum();
    System.out.println(output);

}
}

class DistinctCheck
{
  //private int year = 0;
  private boolean hasDistinctDidgets;
  private int b = 0;
  
  DistinctCheck(int temp)
  {

    hasDistinctDidgets(temp);
  }

  
  private void yearAdd(int b)
{
    while(!hasDistinctDidgets(b)) //if there is repeating digits
    {
      b++;// next year

    }

}
  
private boolean hasDistinctDidgets(int year)
{

  String s = String.valueOf(year); // converts the year from int to String
  int[] numbers = new int[10]; // index position represents number, element value represents occurrence of that number
  for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
  {
    int x = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(i, i + 1)); // integer at this part in the string
    numbers[x]++; //increase occurrence of this integer in the array
  }
  //check if any digit occurred more than once in the array
  for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i ++)
  {
    if (numbers[i] > 1) //digit occurred more than once
    {
      return false; //not distinct
    }
  }
  return true; // hasn't returned false yet, so the integer has distinct digits

}

int getSum()
{
return b;// prints year
}
  

}
```

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. "gives errors" isn't a valid problem description!

Comment: (I entered `somthin` - what the hell are all those "  at  <garbage>"-lines?) In the post editor, use two blanks at the end of lines you want a line break after. Consider making "quoted" input&output stand out. How exactly does `I keep getting errors` manifest?

Comment: enter sothin is just lazy programing, sorry.  u need to enter a 3 or 4 didget number that does not have distinct didgets. the errors I get are out of bounds for the array:                                                       java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4

Answer (score 1):

I would start with a method to determine if a given `int` consists of distinct digits. You could use a `Set<Character>` and add each character from the `String` to the `Set`. You will get `false` on a duplicate. Like,

```
static boolean distinctDigits(int i) {
    String s = String.valueOf(i);
    Set<Character> set = new HashSet<>();
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (!set.add(c)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then your `main` just needs to invoke that. Like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int v = s.nextInt();
    while (v < 10000) {
        v++;
        if (distinctDigits(v)) {
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(v);
}
```

Comment: thank you for the help, the only thing is, I don't really understand: Set<Character> set = new HashSet<>(); and i dont understand : if (!set.add(c)). we have not learned the .add and i have not used the Character class before. i have found an answer online that makes sense, but the only thing is I can not put it in a class, and in order to complete this assignment It must be in a class and not a method. I really do appreciate your help though.

Comment: i added another bit of code to the original question, this code i can understand, but the only thing is, i can not put the processing in a class, I have tried for hours but i cant seem to do the :                                                                     while (!hasDistinctDidgets(n)) //if there is repeating didgets
    {
      n++;// next year
    }                                                                                                                               inside the class or in the main method. Your help is highly appreciated

Comment: @Dante.d360 Works here. Not sure why you're struggling. You need to tell us what the problem is. What error do you get? Simply saying "I have tried for hours but I cant seem to do the".... doesn't tell us what is stopping you. It literally just worked when I ran your currently posted code. BTW, in English the word is "digits". **Not** didgets.

Comment: I know the second bit of code works, but I need help putting it into a class. for ex. class: processing and in this class contains the boolean method and returns the answer to an accessor method wich returns the value to the main method so it can be printed out. the original code i posted did not work though, it was a failed attempt at solving the problem another way.

Comment: You don't have a class `processing`. You don't have an "accessor method". Why does your boolean method need an accessor method? Why can't you call your boolean method from your `Thegoodone` class? I did. It worked.

Comment: I wish I could answer it like that, if i could I would not have a problem. but unfortunately my computer science teacher is 55 years old and he wont take the answer unless its in a class. I'll post how I tried to put this in a class, it runs but outputs 0 for some reason. thanks for helping me out btw

Comment: In what way is `Thegoodone` not a class? And you should try your debugger if it runs but outputs 0.

Comment: I know its a class, i don't know why he wants it like that, probably for scope of code, but that's how he wants it.

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Apple
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
  {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      int num = input.nextInt();
      Distinct findDistinct = new Distinct(num); // objecct
      String output = findDistinct.getDistinctYear();
      System.out.println(output);

  }
} // end of main

 class Distinct
 {
   private int ctr = 0;
   private String yearStr = "";
   private String distinctYear = "";
   private int year = 0;

   Distinct(int n)
   {
     year = n;
     makeDistinct();
   }

   private void makeDistinct()
   {
     while(ctr == 0)
     {
       year += 1; // year will keep increasing until it is distinct
       yearStr = Integer.toString(year);
       if(isDistinct(yearStr) == true) // if the number is distinct
       {
         distinctYear = yearStr;
         ctr++;
       }
     }
   }

  private boolean isDistinct(String yearStr)
  {
    String eachNum[] = yearStr.split(""); // breaks up each number (char) of yearStr
    for(int i = 0; i < eachNum.length; i++)  
    {
      for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
      {
        if (eachNum[i].equals(eachNum[j])) // not distinct
        {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    return true; // is distinct
  }

  String getDistinctYear()
  {
    return distinctYear;
  }

}
```